# unable to identify SAP objects correctly by UFT

Tags: automation, scripting, qtp, sap-gui

I'm having trouble in identifying SAP GUI objects.

instead of UFT recording the objects like:

```
SAP("Title").
```

it records the objects like:

```
Window("Maintain Business Partner").WinEdit("Edit").Set
```

I have performed the necessary troubleshooting steps:

- Enabling scripting in SAP client and Server side
- Install SAP add-ins
- all the steps listed in UFT SAP support page:
  http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/z_Ch_SAPAddin_SAPWin_OV.htm

I've also tried upgrading UFT to ver 14 but it didn't solve the problem.

has anyone encountered this issue and how were you able to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use the object spy and add the objects in the code from OR using drag and drop. In this way, you will not face object mismatch problems. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get Automation developer access. This can resolve your issue.